# Compiling JavaScript inside of Java with Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm testing out Rhino JavaScript script engine inside my Java application.

At startup, I load all .js files and compile them inside of Java like this:

- [Are there any tips & tricks for making rhino perform faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966607/rhino-performance-tricks/7537289#7537289)
- http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t87870.html

That is all well and great, but the offline .js->java .class compiler: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/jsc.html has all sorts of fancy optimizations: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/opt.html

How do I compile inside of Java with those optimizations?

Also were is their API docs for this?  Their API doc link on their main page is broke; http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/doc.html

Edit: I can't use the offline compiler because I want it to be easy for users to drag/drop their scripts in and restart.

Answer (score 0):

`Main.java` inside `toolsrc\org\mozilla\javascript\tools\jsc\` should give you some idea how to do it.

Basically, you set optimization level using `CompilerEnvirons` class. After that, you should create a new instance of the `ClassCompiler` object using `CompilerEnvirons` as the first parameter.

From the source:

```
compilerEnv = new CompilerEnvirons();
...
compiler = new ClassCompiler(compilerEnv);
...
compilerEnv.setOptimizationLevel(optLevel);
```